# Does block within foreach statement have to be only one line long?

Tags: java, coding-style

I'm reading a book called [Clean Code -A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) written by **Robert C. Martin** and in his book he gives a lot of useful tips how to write good Java code.

And one of those tips is:

> Blocks within if statements, else statements, for statements, and so
> on should be one line long. Probably that line should be a function
> call. Not only does this keep the enclosing function small, but it
> also adds documentary value because the function called within the
> block can have a nicely descriptive name

For me that was very strange hint, because from this code:

```
public Map<String, List<Issue>> mapComponentToIssueList(List<Issue> issues) {
    Map<String, List<Issue>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Issue>>();

    for (Issue issue : issues) {
        String componentName = issue.getComponents().iterator().next().getString("name");
        if (map.containsKey(componentName)) {
            map.get(componentName).add(issue);
        } else {
            List<Issue> list = new ArrayList<Issue>();
            list.add(issue);
            map.put(componentName, list);
        }
    }
    return map;

}
```

Using this principle I've got this:

```
public Map<String, List<Issue>> mapComponentToIssueList(List<Issue> issues) {
    Map<String, List<Issue>> componentNameIssueListMap = new HashMap<String, List<Issue>>();
    for (Issue issue : issues) {
        populateMapWithComponenNamesAndIssueLists(componentNameIssueListMap, issue);
    }
    return componentNameIssueListMap;
}

private void populateMapWithComponenNamesAndIssueLists(Map<String, List<Issue>> componentNameIssueListMap, Issue issue) {
    String componentName = getFirstComponentName(issue);
    if (componentNameIssueListMap.containsKey(componentName)) {
        componentNameIssueListMap.get(componentName).add(issue);
    } else {
        putIssueListWithNewKeyToMap(componentNameIssueListMap, issue, componentName);
    }
}

private void putIssueListWithNewKeyToMap(Map<String, List<Issue>> componentNameIssueListMap, Issue issue, String componentName) {
    List<Issue> list = new ArrayList<Issue>();
    list.add(issue);
    componentNameIssueListMap.put(componentName, list);
}

private String getFirstComponentName(Issue issue) {
    return issue.getComponents().iterator().next().getString("name");
}
```

So basically the code has doubled in size.Was it useful? - Maybe.

What code in my example is so called *clean*? What am I doing wrong? What do you guys think about this?

Comment: IMHO, that advice is bordering on ridiculous.

Comment: Please throw out that book. Or burn it. (The latter is safer; no one else will ever be able to read it).

Comment: This only has aesthetic relevance.

Comment: Oh no, it has relevance in that some day I might have to untangle a mess written by someone who did it. **Burn it** :-D

Comment: +1 for the burning, I read that darn book as well and I'm still having nightmares

Comment: @NPE,what do you recommend for reading instead of this book?

Comment: @RicardoSimmus: My advice as far as finding a good book is to formulate what you expect from it, and then ask on http://http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @U-No-Poo: What possessed you? :)

Comment: I was young and dumb. Also: alcohol. :)
Its the Necronomicon in disguise, Iä, Iä, Clean Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, I think the tip is silly because it's so extreme.

Personally, if I were to do anything to your function, I'd change it like so:

```
public Map<String, List<Issue>> mapComponentToIssueList(List<Issue> issues) {
    Map<String, List<Issue>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Issue>>();

    for (Issue issue : issues) {
        String componentName = issue.getComponents().iterator().next().getString("name");
        List<Issue> list = map.get(componentName);
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<Issue>();
            map.put(componentName, list);
        }
        list.add(issue);
    }
    return map;
}
```

The benefits are:

1. You only do the map lookup once instead of twice.
2. The `list.add()` call is not duplicated in two places.

Now if you wanted to factor something out, the following would be a good candidate:

```
        List<Issue> list = map.get(componentName);
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<Issue>();
            map.put(componentName, list);
        }
```

I would definitely do it if the above appeared in more than one place. Otherwise, probably not (at least not initially).

Answer (score 1):

I think it makes more sense to simplify the condition itself. Than the content of the if block, i.e.

```
public void method(){
...
  if( mycondition1 && mycondition2 && mycondition3 && mycondition4 && mycondition5 && mycondition6 && mycondition7 && mycondition8 ) {
   dosomething();
  }
...
}
```

becomes

```
public void method(){
...
  if( conditionsAreTrue() ) {
   dosomething();
  }
...
}

boolean conditionsAreTrue(){
return  mycondition1 && mycondition2 && mycondition3 && mycondition4 && mycondition5 && mycondition6 && mycondition7 && mycondition8;
}
```

Comment: I can't read the book author's mind, but I doubt this is what he meant. Among other things, he is talking about "blocks ... within `else` statements".

Comment: I guess it makes sense in term of reducing complexity but that should be true for any block of code, not just if statement. If a block of code is not straight forward, then extracting it in a method makes the code easier to read and understand.